# my table is a bit cramped

Tags: tables

My table is a but tight. Can you help me? Maybe I just need to reduce the font size? Thanks in advance!

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{amsmath,geometry}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2} % Times Roman math font
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\captionsetup[table]{font=small,
                     labelfont=bf,
                     singlelinecheck=no}

\title{\LARGE \bf ECON 425 Term Paper}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Summary Statistics}
\label{tab:table2}
    \raggedright
    CEO Compensation, 2010-2017
    \medskip

    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \small
    \makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}Lllll@{}}
    \toprule
   &  \thead[l]{Salary} 
   &  \thead[l]{Bonus}
   &  \thead[l]{Stock \\Awards}
   &  \thead[l]{Total \\Compensation}
   \\
    \midrule
    N        & 12,727     &  12,727  & 12,727  & 12,717  \\
    Mean     & 826.36     & 185.17   & 2,583.90  & 6441.41  \\
   \addlinespace
    Median   & 785.00     & 0.00   & 1,495.12   & 4,515.53  \\
    Min      & 0.00     &  -8.72  & -655.00  & 0.00  \\
    Max      & 8,100     & 27,549.88   & 131,939.70  & 156,077.91  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\smallskip
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Update for Bernard (why isn't the @ sign working?): I got interesting results when I tried your code.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{balance}
%\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2} % Times Roman math font
\usepackage{mathptmx} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\captionsetup[table]{font=small,
                     labelfont=bf,
                     singlelinecheck=no}

%for a border
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{boxed} 
\restylefloat{figure}

\begin{document}

\section{INTRODUCTION}
In this paper I estimate the link between shareholder wealth and CEO salary. There has been much interest in this topic for almost a century, albeit mixed empirical results. In firm theory, optimal contracting views executive compensation as designed to minimize the agency costs that exist between executives and shareholders. The so called principle-agent problem arises when executives, the agents, act out of self interest and engage in activities that do not benefit the shareholders, or principles. Estimating the pay-performance sensitivity is fundamental to anyone questioning the size of CEO paychecks or wondering if they are paid enough. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

FOR MICO (having trouble implementing your code):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{amsmath,geometry}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2} % Times Roman math font
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\captionsetup[table]{font=small,
                     labelfont=bf,
                     singlelinecheck=no}

%MICO's CODE:
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}

\usepackage{amsmath,geometry,siunitx,booktabs, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\mC[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C@{}}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\sisetup{group-separator={,}, group-minimum-digits=4}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{font=small, labelfont=bf, singlelinecheck=no}


%for borders on figures
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{boxed} 
\restylefloat{figure}

\title{\LARGE \bf ECON 425 Term Paper}

\author{}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\small
\caption{Summary Statistics} \label{tab:table2}

CEO Compensation, 2010--2017

\medskip
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}
   l S[table-format=4.2] S[table-format=5.2]
   *{2}{S[table-format=6.2]} @{}}
\toprule
& \mC{Salary} & \mC{Bonus} & \mC{Stock Awards} & \mC{Total Comp.} \\
\midrule
$N$    & {12,727} & {12,727} & {12,727} & {12,717}  \\
\addlinespace
Mean   & 826.36   & 185.17   & 2583.90   & 6441.41  \\ 
Median & 785.00   & 0.00     & 1495.12   & 4515.53  \\
Min    & 0.00     &  -8.72   & -655.00   & 0.00     \\
Max    & 8100.00  & 27549.88 & 131939.70 & 156077.91\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried abbreviating `Compensation` to `Comp`. in the header?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution that aligns the numbers on their decimal markers. Hopefully, that'll make the table's contents easier to read.

[image]

About the tabularx code: The left-column column has type `l`, and the four data columns have type `S` (defined by the `siunitx` package). To make it "work" within the `tabularx` framework, the four headers over the data columns are of (modified) type `X`.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}

\usepackage{amsmath,geometry,siunitx,booktabs, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\mC[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C@{}}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\sisetup{group-separator={,}, group-minimum-digits=4}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{font=small, labelfont=bf, singlelinecheck=no}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\small
\caption{Summary Statistics} \label{tab:table2}

CEO Compensation, 2010--2017

\medskip
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}
   l S[table-format=4.2] S[table-format=5.2]
   *{2}{S[table-format=6.2]} @{}}
\toprule
& \mC{Salary} & \mC{Bonus} & \mC{Stock Awards} & \mC{Total Comp.} \\
\midrule
$N$    & {12,727} & {12,727} & {12,727} & {12,717}  \\
\addlinespace
Mean   & 826.36   & 185.17   & 2583.90   & 6441.41  \\ 
Median & 785.00   & 0.00     & 1495.12   & 4515.53  \\
Min    & 0.00     &  -8.72   & -655.00   & 0.00     \\
Max    & 8100.00  & 27549.88 & 131939.70 & 156077.91\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's remark that combining his preamble and mine produce an option class: Moving what you marked as "Mico's code" to the front and taking care not to load packages more than once gets rid of all conflicts:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
% "MICO's CODE"
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}

\usepackage{amsmath,geometry,siunitx,booktabs, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\newcommand\mC[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C@{}}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\sisetup{group-separator={,}, group-minimum-digits=4}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{font=small, labelfont=bf, singlelinecheck=no}

%% Remaining Code: Be sure not to reload any already-loaded packages

\usepackage{%booktabs, 
            makecell, %tabularx
            }
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\raggedbottom
%\usepackage{amsmath,geometry}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
%\usepackage{siunitx}
%\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{balance}
%\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2} % Times Roman math font
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{footmisc}
%\captionsetup[table]{font=small,
%                     labelfont=bf,
%                     singlelinecheck=no}

%for borders on figures
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{boxed} 
\restylefloat{figure}
```

Comment: Mico, your example looks awesome, but when I added your packages, I got all sorts of errors. Is there a more effective way to add your packages rather than just copy and pasting them in (in addition to mine?)

Comment: @texmex - Would you be able to provide a bit more information about the "all sorts of errors"? For sure, I don't think my code loads any packages that aren't also featured in your (longer) preamble.)

Comment: here's one: "Option clash for package textcomp."

Comment: I suspect that one or more packages are being loaded more than once, with possibly incompatible options. A piece-meal approach isn't likely to be productive. Please post a new query, in which you provide both your preamble as well as my code, and ask for help with sorting things out.

Comment: Okay. Please see update.

Comment: @texmex - Please see the addendum I posted. In my experience, it's usually a good idea to load all font-related packages early on in the preamble. For sure, that seems to work here.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{balance}
%\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2} % Times Roman math font
\usepackage{mathptmx} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\captionsetup[table]{font=small,
                     labelfont=bf,
                     singlelinecheck=no}

\title{\LARGE \bf ECON 425 Term Paper}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Summary Statistics}
\label{tab:table2}
    \raggedright
    \small\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\small}
    CEO Compensation, 2010-2017
    \medskip

    \small\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\small}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
   \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\rowcolors{4}{Gainsboro!60!Lavender}{WhiteSmoke!75!Lavender}
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{Lllll}
    \toprule
\rowcolor{white} & \thead[l]{Salary}
   & \thead[l]{Bonus}
   & \thead[l]{Stock \\Awards}
   & \thead[l]{Total \\Compen.}
   \\
    \specialrule{\lightrulewidth}{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
    N & 12,727 & 12,727 & 12,727 & 12,717 \\
    Mean & 826.36 & 185.17 & 2,583.90 & 6441.41 \\[0.5ex]
  % \addlinespace
    Median & 785.00 & 0.00 & 1,495.12 & 4,515.53 \\
    Min & 0.00 & -8.72 & -655.00 & 0.00 \\
    Max & 8,100 & 27,549.88 & 131,939.70 & 156,077.91 \\[\aboverulesep]
    \specialrule{\heavyrulewidth}{0pt}{0pt}
\end{tabularx}

\smallskip
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Bernard, it looks great there, but I got some interesting results when I tried this. Please see above.

Comment: @texmex: I copied the code you've added, included the table code, but there's nothing special, except the table goes at the top of the page, due to a missing option `[!htb]`. What did you obtain?